# How to add custom logic to .NET MVC Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I have recently started working with ASP .NET MVC framework. I created an `ASP .NET Web Application` with `MVC` "template". It auto-generated some code for me. Now, I have been looking all over and I can't find the implementation of `Login | Authentication` logic. Here's what I see in the `AccountsController`

```
//
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Obviously, this is the auto-generated code and I am guessing that `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` method is what implements the logic but I can't find the implementation of that method. I check to see definition and it takes me to the declaration of the method simply which looks like this

```
//
    // Summary:
    //     Sign in the user in using the user name and password
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   userName:
    //
    //   password:
    //
    //   isPersistent:
    //
    //   shouldLockout:
    [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(SignInManager<,>.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__29))]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public virtual Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout);
```

I tried to check the `Call Hierarchy` window but it shows no `Implementation` folder for that method.

I just want to leave all the security features and stuff that the framework brought with it untouched because I don't need to change that. I just want to be able to implement the `Authentication` logic however I want. Can it even be done while keeping the built in security features of the template and not having to implement stuff like `Lock access on too many tries` myself?

Comment: It’s in the framework, it’s not implemented in the web site code. What do you want to do exactly with the authentication that you don’t get out of the box? The actual authentication is handled by ASP.NET Identity and you can write a provider that does whatever you want

Comment: Things like login with username, email as well as phone and also just query my already existing MySQL database. I have multiple roles along with different access levels.

Comment: Writing an Identity provider might work, you can reuse a lot of parts from existing ones and just do the parts you want. It’s still not the simplest thing but quite doable. And it would allow you to let the framework to handle everything else nicely.

Comment: Could you point me to some documentation or tutorial of some kind? Or a detailed snippet would be a big help. I want to make sure that I have all the bases covered for a secure Web App and that I don't miss something important trying to write my own implementation which the framework would have covered automatically.